# Mysql database callback

Tags: android, mysql, callback

I am developing an Android app for restaurant management using Mysql database to store and retrieve orders.

I am wondering if there is a way to set a callback to Mysql to get notified when a new insertion is made into a table.
I thought about setting a thread that would throw requests to my database and getting a result back only if the number of row has changed. But it seems to me that such a thread would use a lot of ressources.

If someone has a suggestion he's welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of thread you can use firebase

Comment: When a new insertion is made into a MySQL table fire child change listener from web to firebase

Comment: it seems that you're looking for *Triggers*

Comment: at the android you need to register listeners

Comment: Hi @AkhileshPatil. Could you please be more specific? I have a firebase acount, but i don't know how to connect my mysql database to it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Maxwell Daemon](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) to monitor the mysql binary logs updates and then send the notification.